# How set command in background,close terminal and get it back to fg?

Tags: bash, process

I'm trying to find out how to run a command in the background and then bring it to the foreground later. I'm fed up of tutorials and answers where people state that it's simple, just append `&` to the end of the command to get it run in the background. It's working only within  a single terminal window. I want to put the command into the background in one terminal and get it back to foreground after reopening the terminal

Example:

```
$ grunt &
$ jobs
$ [1]+  Running  grunt &
```

Of course after closing terminal no one job is found.

Next example:

```
$ grunt & disown #the same behavior has: $ setsid grunt &
$ jobs
$ [nothing] #but ps shows that grunt is working

after close terminal, grunt doesn't work
```

What did I do wrong? Could anybody explain me how to run the command in the background and get it back to foreground.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's impossible in the way you want.

Let's review some basic concepts:

- A process group is a collection of related processes which can all be signalled at once.
- A session is a collection of process groups, which are either attached to a single terminal device (known as the controlling terminal) or not attached to any terminal.

If you closed the terminal, all the processes in the session are dead except those (daemons) reparented to the init process. And there's no way to give them a controlling terminal again.

In a word, process reparenting is highly restricted in POSIX systems (daemonizing is an exception) and your requirements can't be satisfied.

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer, but I believe visitors who are having this problem will find "their solution" in the other answers mentioning screen/byobu/tmux.

Comment: You are right.., but from my point of view, the basic concepts are more important to understand system working better and understand what you want and doing wrong. Thank you both!

Answer (score 17):

1. Install `screen`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install screen
   ```
2. Start `screen`:

   ```
   screen -S session_name
   ```
3. Execute your commands what you need.
4. Detach `screen` from the terminal (your commands will be still running):

   Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
5. Close the terminal
6. Open another terminal and reattach the last `screen` session:

   ```
   screen -r
   ```

For more information and extra options for `screen` look in `man screen`.

Comment: Screen or byobu (especially if you are running ubuntu). Byobu is based on screen if I'm correct, but I find that it has extra functionality that I find useful and easier to use, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank you good suggestion! Maybe It will be need in the feature!) From Russia with love <3

Comment: @Programster, yeah, Byobu is ex. screen. It has both byobu-screen and byobu-tmux.

Comment: I recommend [`tmux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tmux) as an alternative to `screen`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried: `byobu` or `tmux` which are terminal multiplexers. Not exactly what you are looking for, but it has similar behavior.

```
byobu-screen
```

Then run your command, to detach:

```
byobu-screen -d
```

To resume:

```
byobu-screen -r
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen

Comment: Those ones also, +1.